# Adding images inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have the following dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['variant1'], 
                   ['variant2'],
                   ['variant3']],
                   columns = ['variant_title'])

images = ['https://ic.maxabout.us//cars/maruti/maruti-suzuki-swift-sport//Maruti_Suzuki_Swift_Sport_11.jpg',
          'https://ic.maxabout.us//cars/maruti/maruti-suzuki-swift-sport//Maruti_Suzuki_Swift_Sport_15.jpg',
          'https://ic.maxabout.us//cars/maruti/maruti-suzuki-swift-sport//Maruti_Suzuki_Swift_Sport_12.jpg' ] 
df['url']= images         
df
```

Using following code, i am generating figure below.

```
def Path_to_image_html(path):
    return '<img src="'+ path + '" width="180" >'
# Rendering the dataframe as HTML table
df.to_html(escape=False, formatters=dict(url=Path_to_image_html))
# Rendering the images in the dataframe using the HTML method.
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False,formatters=dict(url=Path_to_image_html)))
```

output

[image]

I am facing difficulty while plotting in reverse order i.e.

All the variant on same level and below all the image on same level.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to pivot the DataFrame and collapse it in a single row. That's a possible method:

```
df.index=[0]*len(df)
df=df.pivot(index=None, columns="variant_title", values="url")
```

Comment: Yes, you are on right track. I got the variant names and values as url. Instead of url text in values I want image of cars(HTML view) from those links. Do u know how to replace those urls from images?